# How do i make tags visible in my current Tumblr theme?

Tags: html, tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I made a Tumblr blog with a custom theme, but the theme blocks tags from my posts being visible. What changes do i have to make to the HTML?

This is the theme I'm currently using: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/soft-codes/themes/main/november

I've tried inserting this

```
{block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
      <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
```

just before {/block:Posts} but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This looks correct. Silly question but assuming the `{HasTags}` block is definitely inside the `{block:Posts}` block? And that your posts have tags. Can you just insert some text there as well and make sure it is outputting something?